# Autorelease pool page corrupted

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest, nsautoreleasepool

Whenever I am using ASIHTTPRequest for making webservice calls I am randomly getting the following crash:

```
autorelease pool page 0x9418000 corrupted  
  magic a1a1a100 4f545541 454c4552 21455341  
  pthread 0xb0103000
```

My code is ARC-fied and used -fno-objc-arc for the .m files of ASIHTTP class.

Does anybody have an idea about this or did anybody face this kind of issue before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope that is `-fno-objc-arc` not `-fno -objc -arc`

Answer (score 3):

This likely indicates that you're stomping memory somewhere else. I'd start by turning on [memory diagnostics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) and looking for mistakes. The most likely place to cause these kinds of mistakes is in C code, particularly when using C arrays or C strings. You're probably writing outside of your allocated memory, or writing into memory after you freed it.

There have at times been [compiler bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843774/stack-corrupted-with-autoreleasepool-arc-compiled-with-llvm-3-0-fastest-sma) that would cause this kind of problem, but these are very rare, and I would strongly suspect your code first.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob pointed out, this is likely an indication that you're misusing memory elsewhere. To turn on memory management diagnostics as of Xcode 8:

- Click the scheme menu in Xcode and choose "Edit Scheme..." at the bottom.
- In the Run step, go to the Diagnostics tab.
- Under Memory Management, turn on all four options. I generally find Guard Malloc to uncover the most problems but they can all be useful.